# Archivos en contenedor Flask de docker-compose no se actualizan cuando hago un cambio

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose

Tengo un contenedor Flask que convive junto a otros Django, Celery, Redis, etc, en una aplicación con docker-compose.

El problema es sencillo, cada vez que hago un cambio en el código, tengo que "rebuildear" (docker-compose build) todos los contenedores, lo que hace que mis horas de trabajo se multipliquen.

He visto varios posts pero ninguno da con la solución, ya que en todos la solución que se propone es hacer un volumen, pero como podreis ver, lo hago en mi archivo local.yml

Este es el contenedor en local.yml

```
  flask:
     build:
     context: .
     dockerfile: ./compose/production/flask/Dockerfile
     ports:
       - "5090:5090"
     env_file:
       - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
       - ./.envs/.production/.api
     environment:
     FLASK_DEBUG: 1
     FLASK_APP: ./etl/app.py
     depends_on:
      - postgres
     links:
      - postgres
     volumes: ['./flask:/app']
```

Y este mi Dockerfile

```
    FROM python:3.6
    WORKDIR /etl
    ADD . /etl
    COPY ./requirements /requirements
    RUN pip install --upgrade pip --no-cache-dir -r /requirements/etl.txt
    COPY . .
    CMD ["python","./etl/app.py"]
```

Los archivos Flask están en la carpeta etl, del directorio raiz del sitio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando tu app flask fuera de docker, esta recarga al notar cambios?

Lo correcto en este caso es montontarte un bind volume en la carpeta donde esta tu código python, que basicamente lo que hace es que le decis a tu contenedor que use una carpeta de tu maquina local, como su fuera suya, tu docker-compose quedaria asi:

```
flask:
     build:
     context: .
     dockerfile: ./compose/production/flask/Dockerfile
     ports:
       - "5090:5090"
     env_file:
       - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
       - ./.envs/.production/.api
     environment:
     FLASK_DEBUG: 1
     FLASK_APP: ./etl/app.py
     depends_on:
      - postgres
     links:
      - postgres
     volumes: 
       -./flask:/app
       -./:/etl
```

En este caso deduje que tu `app.py` esta en la misma carpeta donde esta el Dockerfile, en el caso de que esto no sea así, tenes que apuntar el directorio donde esta tu archivo `app.py` hacia el directorio `/etl` de tu container.